# Prevent splash-screen showing an icon in the start-bar

Tags: winapi

For a game project, we found some old win32 code on the web to display a splash-screen, and I noticed it puts an icon on the start-bar. This looks weird because then when the app creates its own window, you see the icon in the startbar disappear and reappear as the splash window is destroyed and the main app window created.

Is it possible to make the splash-screen HWND not shown on the start-bar with some style or window class setting?

Comment: The taskbar icon appears when the window has the WS_EX_APPWINDOW style flag.  Don't use WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW.  And don't force SO users to guess at what your code looks like.

Comment: @HansPassant Actually, `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` is just one way to force it onto the taskbar. The other is having no owner. Using `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` is an easy way to keep the window off the taskbar. An alternative is to give the window an owner.

Comment: @HansPassant this is SO not GitHub. A question about windows styles doesn't require source code, as evidenced by the fact you were able to answer the question in the first place.

Comment: Sure, it also is not youtube.com or a forum.  Whether the comment was relevant or an answer is hard to see, you appeared to like David's comment better.  Nobody can guess why.

Comment: If you're going to complain about not using SO properly, I could very well tell you that you shouldn't provide an answer in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my splash screens I use these extendes window styles: `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW|WS_EX_TOPMOST` 
and these window styles: `WS_POPUP|WS_VISIBLE`

No taskbar icon shows up with this combination of styles.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways.  One is to make it owned by another top-level window that is hidden.

For example, you can create your main window, but don't show it.  Then create the splash screen as an owned window (with your main window as the owner).  Show the splash screen.  Do your initialization.  Then show the main window and destroy the splash screen.